# Importance of var keyword in Kotlin enum class constructor declaration

Tags: kotlin, enums, var

```
 enum class Admin(myName:String, val id:Int, val age:Int){
    ROOT_ADMIN ("Pete", 1, 55),
    ACADEMIC_ADMIN("Jacob",11,56),
    DEPARTMENT_ADMIN("Robin",111,50),
    CLASS_ADMIN("Chris",1111,22)
```

To access the properties of objects of enum class **Admin**, when I type

```
Admin.CLASS_ADMIN.____
```

Naturally, `myName` to come out in the IDE auto-complete is expected. But its not happening. But `id` and `age` does come as they have `val` keyword associated with them.

But when I add `var` in front of myName, like:

```
enum class Admin(var myName:String, val id:Int, val age:Int)
```

I am now getting myName in auto-complete.

What is the importance of `var` keyword here?

Note: I am aware of the fact that when we declare variables with var or val keywords in constructor, it declares a property inside that class.
But how this logic relates to this situation?

Comment: "when we declare variables with var or val keywords in constructor, it declares a property inside that class." Yes, but do you understand what a "property" is?

Comment: If I'm right, it is the variable which hold some value and is associated with each instance of the class.

Comment: Yeah, so without `var` or `val`, there's no "variable which hold some value and is associated with each instance of the class" in `Admin` that stores `myName`, so you can't access it with `Admin.CLASS_ADMIN.myName`. I don't understand what exactly you are confused about if you have understood this much lol.

Comment: If it helps, `enum class Admin(myName:String, val id:Int, val age:Int)` is just a constructor like for any other class, so `myName` (without the `val`) is just a constructor parameter you can only access during initialisation. If you want it to be accessible later, you need to create a property and assign `myName`'s value to it. Putting `val` or `var` in the constructor is just a nice shorthand for doing that

Answer (score 3):

This is more about Kotlin properties and less about how val/var work with enums. In fact for most of this answer, we can completely ignore the fact that we're even talking about enums, as opposed to any other Kotlin class (but I do have a note at the end on this).

For background, when you create an instance of a class in Kotlin and provide arguments to its constructor, if those arguments have `var` or `val`, Kotlin will treat them as properties. If not, it treats them as an argument to the constructor (these can be used in `init` blocks, for example but do not get turned into properties).

That's what is happening in your case. Kotlin treats `myName` as a constructor argument and *effectively* throws it away as you aren't using it. It does not get turned into a property. For `id` and `age`, you've specified they are `val`, so Kotlin turns them into read-only properties.

As for `var`, when Kotlin sees this it makes them into a read/write property (they can change).

**Basically:** Kotlin turned `id` and `age` into read-only properties and `myName` was defined as a constructor argument. This is why autocomplete did not offer you `myName`, it wasn't a property.

**Some general advice**: I would absolutely not declare any mutable properties on an enum (so, use `val` only for read-only properties). By using `var`, you'll get mutable read/write properties. Normally that's fine but with enum specifically there is an expectation that they do not change, ever. You are declaring a fixed set of values (an *enumeration* of them!) whose internal properties do not change. As a developer if I saw an enum whose internal state was mutable, it would immediately seem wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since item of `enum class` is acting like `object` in Kotlin (just for understanding), if you declare property as `var` of enum class, you could change the property value and it affects everywhere. This might be hard to understand. You can see below example code.

```kotlin
enum class Test(var a: String) {
    A("a"),
    B("b");
}

fun main()
{
    println(Test.A.a) // a

    Test.A.a = "b"

    println(Test.A.a) // b
}
```

Usually, you might not want to declare a property as mutable for the design.